# Simulating random variable from exp( AR(1))

Tags: random-variables, time-series, simulation, jensen-inequality

I am assuming that an observed value $\hat Y_t$ is simulated from a known true value $Y_t$. I am also assuming that there is a log-normally distributed error that displays an AR1 process thus 
 $\hat Y_t = Y_t * e^{X_t}$ , and
 $X_t = c + \rho*X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

I took the natural log of the observed value minus the natural log of the true value and fit an AR(1) process to these errors ($X_t = ln(\hat Y_t) - ln(Y_t)$ ) using the arima function in R to estimate the coefficients for $c , \rho$ and the variance of $\epsilon_t$.

I now want to simulate a process that has the same variance and mean of the observed process. However, I am concerned that by using the estimated coefficients to simulate the AR(1) process and exponentiating the resulting random variables will result in a mean biased process

How would I simulate values for $\hat Y_t$ given the estimates so that the simulated values have the same mean and variance as the observed data?

Comment: What is $Y_t$? $\!$

Comment: $Y_t$ in this context is the total allowable catch calculated using a harvest policy and a known population abundance. $\hat Y_t$ is the total allowable catch calculated from the harvest policy and a population abundance estimated from a different model. I didn't think it was relevant to the question so I didn't include that. Similar processes are often also assumed when simulating the recruitment (i.e., # of births) of a population.